# MX Anywhere 3 adjust scrolling speed

Tags: driver, logitech

I got Logitech MX Anywhere 3 mouse and I am using on Ubuntu. I have installed the drivers and I am using `logid` to configure it. However I cannot manage to adjust the scrolling speed using the `logid.cfg` file. Any ideas on how to do that?

```
// Logiops (Linux driver) configuration for Logitech MX Master 3.
// Includes gestures, smartshift, DPI.
// Tested on logid v0.2.3 - GNOME 3.38.4 on Zorin OS 16 Pro
// What's working:
//   1. Window snapping using Gesture button (Thumb)
//   2. Forward Back Buttons
//   3. Top button (Ratchet-Free wheel)
// What's not working:
//   1. Thumb scroll (H-scroll)
//   2. Scroll button

// File location: /etc/logid.cfg

devices: ({
  name: "MX Anywhere 3";

  smartshift: {
    on: true;
    threshold: 5;
  };

  hiresscroll: {
    hires: true;
    invert: true;
    target: false;
  };

  dpi: 1200; // max=4000

  buttons: (
    // Forward button
    {
      cid: 0x56;
      action = {
        type: "Gestures";
        gestures: (
          {
            direction: "None";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_FORWARD" ];
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Up";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_PLAYPAUSE" ];
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Down";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_LEFTMETA" ];
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Right";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_NEXTSONG" ];
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Left";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_PREVIOUSSONG" ];
            }
          }
        );
      };
    },

    // Back button
    {
      cid: 0x53;
      action = {
        type: "Gestures";
        gestures: (
          {
            direction: "None";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_BACK" ];
            }
          }
        );
      };
    },

    // Gesture button (hold and move)
    {
      cid: 0xc3;
      action = {
        type: "Gestures";
        gestures: (
          {
            direction: "None";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_LEFTMETA" ]; // open activities overview
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Right";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_LEFTMETA", "KEY_RIGHT" ]; // snap window to right
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Left";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_LEFTMETA", "KEY_LEFT" ];
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Up";
            mode: "onRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_LEFTMETA", "KEY_UP" ]; // maximize window
            }
          },
          
          {
            direction: "Down";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "Keypress";
              keys: [ "KEY_LEFTMETA", "KEY_DOWN" ]; // minimize window
            }
          }
        );
      };
    },
    
    // Top button
    {
      cid: 0xc4;
      action = {
        type: "Gestures";
        gestures: (
          {
            direction: "None";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "ToggleSmartShift";
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Up";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "ChangeDPI";
              inc: 1000,
            }
          },

          {
            direction: "Down";
            mode: "OnRelease";
            action = {
              type: "ChangeDPI";
              inc: -1000,
            }
          }
        );
      };
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

look at my configuration:

```
hiresscroll:
    {
      hires: false;
      invert: false;
      target: true;
      up:
      {
        mode: "Axis";
        axis: "REL_WHEEL_HI_RES";
        axis_multiplier: 15;
      },
      down:
      {
        mode: "Axis";
        axis: "REL_WHEEL_HI_RES";
        axis_multiplier: -15;
      },
    };
```

Changing the axis_multiplier will adjust the scrolling speed.